# Apex Mocks - Verify that child is correctly related to a previously registered parent in Unit of Work

Tags: apex, unit-test, fflib, apexmock

I have code where in the same Unit of Work I'm inserting a record and a related record, for example an Account and Contact.

```
Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test acc');
unitOfWork.registerNew(acc);

unitOfWork.registerNew(new Contact(
   LastName = 'Test contact'
), Contact.AccountId, acc);
    
unitOfWork.commitWork();
```

How do I now test that `registerNew()` was called with a correct account? I think I can do it with argument captors, but this produced a ton of hard to read code when I tried to do it. Is there any better way? For now I have created a workaround by matching that an account was passed to registerNew with correct name (`fflib_Match.sObjectWithName`), but I don't think that's a good test, as there may be more than one account registered with the same name (not shown in the example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is unit test code, you should know how many Contacts will be added to the same parent account

Thus, your ApexMocks verify for

```
unitOfWork.registerNew(new Contact(
                          LastName = 'Test contact'
), Contact.AccountId, acc);
```

will be

```
Integer expectedContactsPerAccount = 3;
((fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(mockUow,mocks
          .times(expectedContactsPerAccount)
          .description('should be ' + expectedContactsPerAccount + ' contacts added to Account 'testAccount')))
      .registerNew(fflib_Match.sObjectWith(new Map<SObjectField,Object> {
                                 Contact.LastName => 'Test contact'
                                 }),
                   fflib_Match.eqSObjectField(Contact.AccountId),
                   fflib_Match.sObjectWith(new Map<SObjectField,Object> {
                Account.Name => 'Test acc'
            }));
```

Now, if your code under test could create two Accounts with the same `Account.Name` and *there is no other distinguishing field between the two Accounts*, I'd suggest redesigning your application as creating multiple Accounts with the same Name doesn't seem like good design.

I don't see how ArgumentCaptors will help as `acc.Id` is local to the code under test and you won't have that unless the method returns the inserted Accounts so you can then in turn verify the second `registerNew`

Another approach would be to move the account creation into a different service class and use Apex Mocks answers to return a mocked Account (including Account.Id). Then, you could verify the second registerNew of Contacts against the Apex Mocks Answers of the simulated inserted Accounts.  See [Answering with ApexMocks](https://xonoxforce.wordpress.com/2017/03/31/answering-with-apex-mocks/)

But frankly, when faced with your situation, I'd design my unit test to avoid creating Accounts with duplicate names (and no other disambiguation) so I could reliably verify the registerNew for Contact.